# Write a nested query in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Imagine that I have a table in the database to keep the history of customers' status.

[image]

If I want to get customers from for example status **1001 to 1002**, it’s simple

```
Select * from TableName where StartStatus=1001 and EndStatus=1002
```

If  I want to write a query that returns the customers that change from status **1001 to 1005**, how can I do that?

The result should be just one record for each customer (I need to omit the internal changes for a customer, for example, do not need **1001 to 1002** and **1002 to 1003** and **1003 to 1004**)

For example in this data, the customer with id 2 changed from **1006 to 1005**, then the query shouldn't return it

Comment: I assume the table also has a CustomerId column? You probably need a recursive CTE anyway to follow the path of status changes. Be careful of infinite loops

Comment: I might be missing something but isn't this just a case of looking for where a customer has a record with a StartStatus = 1001 and also a record with an EndStatus = 1005? Can you not inner join to the same table joining on CustomerID (or similar) and then filtering to T1.StartStatus = 1001 and T2.EndStatus = 1005

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, add sample data as text in the quedtion with expected results, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JohnS is Customer 2 excluded based on not having a StartStatus of 1001 or because they 'regressed' to 1005?

Comment: @RickyTillson Customer 1's status journey was `1000 -> 1001 -> 1002 -> 1003 -> 1004 -> 1005`. This includes a path from 1001 to 1005. Customer 2's status journey was just `1006 -> 1005`. This does not include a path from 1001 to 1005

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we're not worried about Customers moving 'backwards' into 1005 as long as there is ever a StartStatus of 1001 and an EndStatus of 1005 this should work

```
CREATE TABLE #Customer (CustomerID INT, StartStatus INT, EndStatus INT)
INSERT INTO #Customer (CustomerID, StartStatus, EndStatus)
VALUES (1, 1000, 1001),
       (1, 1001, 1002),
       (1, 1002, 1003),
       (1, 1003, 1004),
       (1, 1004, 1005),
       (2, 1006, 1005)

SELECT C1.CustomerID, C1.StartStatus, C2.EndStatus
FROM #Customer AS C1
INNER JOIN #Customer AS C2 ON C2.CustomerID = C1.CustomerID 
WHERE C1.StartStatus = 1001 AND C2.EndStatus = 1005
```